# How can I use sed to to convert $$ blah $$ in TeX to \begin{equation} blah \end{equation}

Tags: sed

I have files with entries of the form:

```
$$
y = x^2
$$
```

I'm looking for a way (specifically using sed) to convert them to:

```
\begin{equation}
y = x^2
\end{equation}
```

The solution should not rely on the form of the equation (which may also span mutiple lines) nor on the text preceding the opening $$ or following the closing $$.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed '
  /^\$\$$/ {
    x
    s/begin/&/
    t use_end_tag
    s/^.*$/\\begin{equation}/
    h
    b
    : use_end_tag
    s/^.*$/\\end{equation}/
    h
  }
'
```

Explanation:

`sed` maintains two buffers: the pattern space (pspace) and the hold space (hspace). It operates in cycles, where during each cycle it reads a line and executes the script for that line. pspace is usually auto-printed at the end of each cycle (unless the `-n` option is used), and then deleted before the next cycle. hspace holds its contents between cycles.

The idea of the script is that whenever $$ is seen, hspace is first checked to see if it contains the word "begin". If it does, then substitute the end tag; otherwise substitute the begin tag. In either case, store the substituted tag in the hold space so it can be checked next time.

```
sed '
  /^\$\$$/ {                   # if line contains only $$
    x                          # exchange pspace and hspace
    s/begin/&/                 # see if "begin" was in hspace
    t use_end_tag              # if it was, goto use_end_tag
    s/^.*$/\\begin{equation}/  # replace pspace with \begin{equation}
    h                          # set hspace to contents of pspace
    b                          # start next cycle after auto-printing
    : use_end_tag
    s/^.*$/\\end{equation}/    # replace pspace with \end{equation}
    h                          # set hspace to contents of pspace
  }
'
```

Comment: Works nicely, but, even though I know what each individual command does, I'm too thick to figure out how it works. Could you add some explanation please?

Comment: @user3856370 Is that enough explanation? And you're not thick. `sed` is strange and limited!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
 sed -r '1{x;s/^/\\begin{equation}\n\\end{equation}/;x};/\$\$/{g;P;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\n\1/;h;d}' file
```

Prime the hold space with the required strings. On encountering the marker print the first line and then swap the strings in anticipation of the next marker.

Comment: Why is it all squished onto one line? Still, I like this better than mine. +1

Comment: @ooga no particular reason other than this is the way I write and test my solutions on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I can  not help you with `sed`, but this `awk` should do:

```
awk '/\$\$/ && !f {$0="\\begin{equation}";f=1} /\$\$/ && f {$0="\\end{equation}";f=0}1' file
\begin{equation}
y = x^2
\end{equation}
```

The `f=0`is not needed, if its not repeated.